# Badly written jQuery that is crashing browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I am using a jQuery plugin called Background stretcher and this is the code that is intitialising it. The site starts to hang the more that I press the links in the callback function, so would there be a better way this can be written...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //  Initialize Backgound Stretcher     
    $('BODY').bgStretcher({
        images: ['images/exterior.jpg', 'images/exterior2.jpg','images/kitchen.jpg','images/bathroom.jpg','images/bedroom.jpg'],
        imageWidth: 1800, 
        imageHeight: 1400, 
        slideDirection: 'N',
        slideShowSpeed: 1000,
        nextSlideDelay: 6000,
        transitionEffect: 'fade',
        sequenceMode: 'normal',
        buttonPrev: '.prev',
        buttonNext: '.next',
        pagination: '.pagination',
        anchoring: 'left center',
        anchoringImg: 'left center',
        callbackfunction: function() {

                    $('a#design').click(function(){
                        $().bgStretcher._clearTimeout();
                        $().bgStretcher.slideShow('normal', 0);
                        $().bgStretcher.play();
                    });
                    $('a#interior').click(function(){
                        $().bgStretcher._clearTimeout();
                        $().bgStretcher.slideShow('normal', 1);
                        $().bgStretcher.play();
                    });
                    $('a#lifestyle').click(function(){
                        $().bgStretcher.pause();
                        $().bgStretcher.slideShow('normal', 2);
                        $().bgStretcher.play();
                    });
                    $('a#location').click(function(){
                        $().bgStretcher.pause();
                        $().bgStretcher.slideShow('normal', 3);
                        $().bgStretcher.play();
                    });
                    $('a#contact').click(function(){
                        $().bgStretcher.pause();
                        $().bgStretcher.slideShow('normal', 4);
                        $().bgStretcher.play();
                    });

        }
    });
});
```

What would be a more efficient/cleaner way to write this??

Comment: what is your meaning of `$()` in click function? is `this` or what? how about `$(this)` ??

Comment: use the jquery validator online to validate your jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$()` you should write `$('body')` so try using it this way :

```
.
.
.
//  Initialize Backgound Stretcher     
    $('body').bgStretcher({
.
.
.
.
                    $('a#design').click(function(){
                        $('body').bgStretcher._clearTimeout();
                        $('body').bgStretcher.slideShow('normal', 0);
                        $('body').bgStretcher.play();
                    });
.
.
.
```